# Working With ifNan Function

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble getting the Codecademy section of ifNan done. How do I make it so the ifNan function checks the number I manually input at the end when I run the function. For example:

```
var isEven = function(number) {
if (number % 2 === 0) {
  return true;
} else if (isNan(number))  { 
  return "Your input is not a number!";
} else {
  return false;
} 
};

isEven(2);
```

What would I put in the isNan function so that when I input the number at the bottom it also checks if it is actually a number?

Comment: You should be checking whether the number `isNaN` _before_ you check whether it is an even number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...update to this long-standing issue:

I went back to codecademy and restarted the lesson. After researching for about a week, and a good long breather, I came back to this frustrating issue and even then found myself writing the same exact code that I had in the beginning of this issue (because I knew it was correct).

You all made valid points.

Dennis you're absolutely right this can be condensed in a few areas but Codecademy is very rigid (which I'm liking less and less) so it would have never let me pass the dang section.

Anyways, I wanted to close this but "answer" (kind of) it first.

Thanks for all your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

you could condense that down to:

```
function isEven(number)
{
    if(!isNaN(number) || number % 2 === 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

See elclanrs comment. isNan is not a function isNaN is. caps matter there.

Comment: You could also condense it further: `return !isNaN(number) && number % 2 === 0;`

Comment: right and also should note negative evens will also return true

Comment: @Dennis—or `!isNaN(number) && !!(number % 2)`. :-)

Comment: I'm still not understanding it :( Idk why this part is so difficult for me. Is there a reference someone could point me to? W3schools is kind of sparse and the codecademy section just sucks.

Comment: You mean something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: What does it mean when it says "isNaN is not defined true"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. isNaN means is Not a Number. so isNaN(5) is like saying is 5 not a number? answer: false. cause 5 is a number. The example in that link shows a number of interesting test cases where isNaN returns true or false depending on the input. It seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isEven = function(number) { if (number % 2 === 0) { return true; } else if(isNaN(number) === true || false){ return "your input is not a number"; } else { return false; }// Your code goes here!

}; isEven("Gbemi")
```

Comment: After a week, i was able to crack this issue.